# Gmail is "Clipping" messages that are WELL under the size threshold

Tags: gmail

It's well known that for emails larger than 100kb, Gmail will show a "[Message clipped]" and hide the full message behind the link. However, today I've sent a few emails that are less than 10kb and they're still getting [Message clipped]. Any idea why this is happening? What can I do to prevent it?